# Gridview Items with button on clause

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a page and say 2 textboxes. User enters the details in the Textboxes and clicks on Add button which will then add to Gridview. 
I also have a submit button which will allow user to submit the entered details.

For ex:

```
TextBox1 :
TextBox2 :

  Add to Grid 

Submit
```

This is what I have tried. I have a class for each of these textboxes and I am checking in Jquery like below

```
function Checktxtboxes() {
    var flag = false;
    var nonempty = $('.MyClass').filter(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length = 0) {
            flag=true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!flag) {
       // alert("Add to Grid");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But this method works but doens't do what I actually want. 
User may stop adding rows to Grid after few times but if any of those textboxes contain some value and they didn't go to the grid row only then alert should appear

Now I have a problem. First time user clicks on Add to Grid and second time he enters the details in both textboxes but forgot to click Add to Grid. 
Directly clicks on Submit . So now technically he entered only one row to Grid. But according to him he entered two. 
How to fix the bug? How can I stop the user from not clicking the submit when he entered something in textboxes and forgot to click on Add to grid button.
The below js function is called on Submit button click

```
 function submitjavascript() {
    var totalRows = $("#<%=gridview1.ClientID %> tr").length;
    if (totalRows != 0) {
        //do something

        }
        else {
           //do something
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please Add details to Grid");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am totally dead with this issue

Comment: "How to achieve this?" - achieve what? How do you want to resolve this issue from user experience perspective?

Comment: yeah how do I fix this error is my question.

Comment: You can disable submit button if there's some text in a textbox

Comment: Can you tell how to do this in Jquery

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with javascript but on vb.net I think of 2 ways

You can make the textboxes to clear themselves after the Add to Grid button click, and on the `Submitbutton_click` event you can check for the text in those textboxes, something like this:

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click event
   If textbox1.text <> "" or textbox2.text <> "" Then
   'Add your alert code here, or a pop up window or whatever.

   ElseIf textbox1.text = "" and textbox2.text = "" Then  'User has already clicked Add to grid button so the Textboxes are clear.
   'Here goes the submit code action.
   End if
End sub
```

Or whenever the user access the textbox and the text changed, turn the `Enabled` feature of the Submit Button to `False` and when the Add to Grid button is clicked set this same property to `True`

Hope this helps

**EDIT** ok, so after a bit of research and experiments, this is what I came to,

```
<form id="form1">
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField2" />
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField3" />
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField4" />
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField5" />
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField6" />
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField7" />
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField8" />
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField9" />
  <input name="Details" type="text" id="idField10" />
</form>
```

And your js for the submit button would be like this:

```
 function submitjavascript() 
{
    var allTbs = document.getElementsByName("Details");
    for (var i = 0, max = allTbs.length; i < max; i++) 
      {
        if (allTbs[i].value!="") 
           {
             alert("Please Add details to Grid");
            break;
           }
       }
}
```

However one thing that I noticed is that whenever the alert message comes up, and is clicked ok, the textboxes clear themselves and to be honest I do not know why, like I said, Im pretty new to js

Comment: I have got this solution before posting my question. But in reality I have more than two textboxes. I was thinking if I can find better solution with Jquery or something. Because if the project keeps growing and textboxes keep adding then I have to check like 10+ textboxes in submit.  I would actually this enabled and disabled function

Comment: This seems promising. Howeever, It would still be a Error in user's perspective. What if the user has just two rows to add to grid and then he has to click on submit.  Forexample if a family has three children, user enters each children and add in Grid and the submits. Another user has just one kid then he will just add one row and click on submit. In that case this wont work

Comment: If you add another js to clear every textbox when the add button is clicked or to enable the submit button when is clicked it will work.

The user will populate how many textbox they need, if they dont click the add button, either the submit button will not be enabled and they could not click it (obviously), or the textboxes wont be cleared, and if they click submit, it will show the alert message, cause it checks for clear textboxes. Hope I explained myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable submit buttun until textbox is not empty:

```
        $("#txtboxId").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);
            } else {
                $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        })
```

Comment: First thing. If is not just one textbox. So I need to do this for all? Instead I added a class to those textboxes. But After adding one/two rows to Grid It can enable . But if user enters the text and forgets to click on add grid rows  then is the problem I am talking about